# Getting child class type from parent class parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I am going to have multiple "types" of an object and I am really not sure how best to retrieve/save those multiple types without having a separate save/retrieve for each type.

My classes:

```
public class Evaluation {
  public int Id
  public string Comment
}

public class EvaluationType_1 : Evaluation {
  public string field
}

public class EvaluationType_1 : Evaluation {
  public string field
}
```

What I would like to do in my repository:

```
public interface IEvaluationRepository {
  public Evaluation getEvaluation(int id);
  public SaveEvaluation(Evaluation);
}
```

Inside the get/save methods:

```
// Save/get common fields
Id
Comments

// Get child type, perform switch
Type childType = ???
switch(childType) {
  // Set child-specific fields
}
```

I'd rather not add a "type" column as I have this in another part of my database and I am not really liking it too much

### Update

Here's more info for clarification, if necessary.

I love the idea of using interfaces and generics, I'm really at a loss for how to incorporate them into my repository pattern.

When I call `getEvaluation`, I want it to return an abstract Evaluation, but I'm struggling with this code.  Same with Saving.

### Update 2

Daniel is helping me hone in on what exactly I am trying to ask.

Database:

```
Evaluations
  Id (PK)
  Comment

EvaluationType1
  Id (FK to Evaluations.Id)
  Field

EvaluationType1
  Id (FK to Evaluations.Id)
  Field
```

So, in `getEvaluation(int id)`, I need to figure out what type of Evaluation they want.  Does this mean I should pass in a type?  Same is true in `saveEvaluation`, But I can do a switch/function map to see what `Type` it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public interface ISaveable {
   void SaveFields();
}

public abstract class Evaluation : ISaveable {
  public int Id
  public string Comment

  public virtual void SaveFields() {
     //Save ID and Comments
  }
}

public class EvaluationType_1 : Evaluation {
    public string field1

  public override void SaveFields() {
     //Save field1
     base.SaveFields();
  }

}

public class EvaluationType_2 : Evaluation {
   public string field2

  public override void SaveFields() {
     //Save field2
     base.SaveFields();
  }

}
```

Then you can have a collection of ISaveable such as `List<ISaveable>` and call SaveFields on each one, **regardless** of their type. You are now programming against the interface rather than against concrete types. The first step towards decoupling of code.

**Edited:** In response to your comment
In your repository, you would no longer program against the Evaluation class. Instead you would program agains t the methods in the interface that it implements:

Instead of:

```
public interface IEvaluationRepository {
  public Evaluation getEvaluation(int id);
  public SaveEvaluation(Evaluation);
}
```

You might have:

```
 public interface ISaveableRepository {
   public ISaveable getSavable(int id);
   public Save(ISaveable saveable);
 }
```

And an implementation of the repository might be like:

```
 public class SaveableEvaluationRepository : ISaveableRepository {
   public ISaveable getSavable(int id) {
       //Add your logic here to retrieve your evaluations, although I think that 
       //this logic would belong elsewhere, rather than the saveable interface.
   }

   public Save(ISaveable saveable) {
       saveable.SaveFields();
   }
 }
```

Comment: This looks great, Daniel.  My only concern is how I'd use `saveFields` in conjunction with a `Save` method inside my repository - see my updates +1

Comment: Hey Dan. I have edited my post. I am not 100% happy with it, but it should get you thinking about how to program against interfaces rather than concrete types.

Comment: One other thing that you might want to think about is using a manager class to handle the loading and saving of your entities rather than embedding the logic into the entities themselves.

Comment: Good stuff - Thanks for the edit.  I updated again to see if you can give me an elegant way of getting an evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, still from what I understood, you're looking for the type of the object. Here's how you do it.

```
EvaluationType_1 objOfEvalType1 = new EvaluationType_1();
Type childType = objOfEvalType1.GetType();
```

If you need to the type of child-class in the base/parent class, update your Evaluation class as below.

```
public class Evaluation {
  public int Id;
  public string Comment;

  //call this.GetType() anywhere you wish to get the type of the object.
  public Type MyType = this.GetType();
}
```

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure what I was asking, really (if that makes sense).  Please see my update; I hope it is more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an very good candidate for generics, and a lot of repository and ORM frameworks use them.

```
public interface IEvaluationRepository<TEvaluation> 
{ 
  public TEvaluation getEvaluation(int id); 
  public SaveEvaluation(TEvaluation evaluation); 
}
```

You might also want an EvaluationBase class to handle common functions, and constraint your interface to take only EvaluationBase classes:

```
public interface IEvaluationRepository<TEvaluation> where TEvaluation : EvaluationBase
...
public class SomeEvaluation : EvaluationBase
{
}
```

It would save most or all of the problems of recognizing and tracking object types.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) returns the exact runtime type of the current instance - it does not consider the declaring type of the associated variable:

```
Type type = evaulation.GetType();

// Note that you can't switch on types

if (type == typeof(DerivedEvaluation1)) {
    // Perform custom operations        
}
else if (type == typeof(DerivedEvaluation2)) {
    // Perform custom operations
}

// Etc.
```

Comment: This dispatching logic is exactly what virtual method calls do - I would rather suggest to use virtual methods instead of emulating a virtual dispatch.

Comment: @Daniel - if he were using the active record pattern, I'd agree. But that doesn't seem to be the case here: the persistence logic lives in repository classes distinct from the `Evaluation` inheritance hierarchy. Of course, the repositories could have their own hierarchy ... but that requires moving the dispatch logic into a factory or making the domain objects factories. I think that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as inquiring about a convenient way of dispatching custom save logic without doing "messy" switching on the type of the child object. If all you want is an easy way to gt the type a parameter you can use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx) keyword.

There are a couple of ways of dispatching logic based on runtime type.

One is that you can always create a dispatch dictionary of `Save` functions for each specific type:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type,Action<Evaluation>> s_SaveFunctions =
    new Dictionary<Type,Action<Evaluation>>();

s_SaveFunctions[typeof(ChildA)] = SaveChildA;
s_SaveFunctions[typeof(ChildB)] = SaveChildB;
// .. and so on.

public SaveEvaluation( Evaluation eval )
{
   // .. common save code ...

   // cal the appropriately typed save logic...
   s_SaveFunctions[eval.GetType()]( eval );
}

private static void SaveChildA( Evaluation eval ) { ... }

private static void SaveChildB( Evaluation eval ) { ... }
```

In .NET 4, you could use `dynamic` to achieve a cleaner version of the same:

```
public SaveEvaluation( Evaluation eval )
{
   // .. common save logic ..

   dynamic evalDyn = eval;

   SaveChild( evalDyn );
}

private void SaveChild( ChildA eval ) { ... }

private void SaveChild( ChildB eval ) { ... }
```

Note how the `SaveChild` methods all have the same name, but are just overloaded by the type of their argument. The `dynamic` parameter used in the `SaveEvaluation` method will be evaluated at runtime, and dispatched to the appropriate overload.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your methods virtual - the call will be dispatched to the correct method based on the actual runtime type.

```
public class Evaluation
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        // Save the common information.
        this.SaveToDatabase(this.Id);
        this.SaveToDatabase(this.Comment);
    }

    private void SaveToDatabase(Object value)
    {
        // Left as an exercise for the reader... :D
    }
}

public class EvaluationType1 : Evaluation
{
    public String Foo { get; set; }

    public override void Save()
    {
        // Save the common information.
        base.Save();

        // Save the specific information here.
        this.SaveToDatabase(this.Foo);
    }
}


public class EvaluationType2 : Evaluation
{
    public String Bar { get; set; }

    public override void Save()
    {
        // Save the common information.
        base.Save();

        // Save the specific information here.
        this.SaveToDatabase(this.Bar);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can also make the base class abstract. Further you should usually avoid making fields public accessible - this may turn maintaining the code into a nightmare and therefore I use properties in my example.